php - ldap_search(): search: operations error
I've been trying almost everything to solve this issue, but sadly i couldn't, i'm starting to think that something for inside of my organization but when i asked everyone they told me nothing blocks you, so maybe i'm missing something:
My goal is to search for any user or group in my LDAP on the top of the tree in the active directory, I had php version 8.1 and since that ldap_search issue appeared there i tried to upgrade to version 8.3.6.
<?php
{
    $ldaprdn = "username";
    $ldappass = 'password';
    
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldapserver") or die ("could not connect to LDAP server");
    if($ldapconn)
    {
        print("connected");
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
        $user_to_search = "My_User";
        if($ldapbind)
        {
            print("binded");
            $filter = "(samaccountname=$user_to_search*)";
            $justthese = array("samaccountname");
            $result = ldap_search($ldapconn, "DC=Top,DC=OrganizationTree", $filter, $justthese);
            $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $result);
            print_r($entries);
        }
    }
}
?>

this is the error i get now:
php warnionig: ldap_search(): Search: operations error in...... on line 
Must appriciate for anyone who can shed some light on this issue...
i've also tried to enable "debug mode" in php to get more info about this issue, but sadly i didnt get any more relevant info.
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

or
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');


Can you supply the whole warning message you are getting?

PHP Warning:  ldap_search(): Search: Operations error in ADSearch.php on line 17
basically its this line:
$result = ldap_search($ldapconn, "DC=Top,DC=OrganizationTree", $filter, $justthese);
@Cyclonecode

Maybe a permission issue? Does the user have the right to do the search?

@Olivier The thing is that it sometimes work, sometimes doesnt, it has no rules, i'm starting to think it either has something to do with the PHP files / DLL or some network issues / Security thing
the thing is that if for example i will take the following Base DN:
$result = ldap_search($ldapconn, "OU=IT,DC=Top,DC=OrganizationTree", $filter, $justthese);
Changed from: "DC=Top,DC=OrganizationTree" -> "OU=IT,DC=Top,DC=OrganizationTree" it will work none stop! but the users can be AD groups or users which are not from said OU..

Make sure the user you're binding is allowed to search, also it might be good to test setting the protocol version and allow referrals e.g. ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

@Cyclonecode Thanks, i've already tried that and that didnt work, im gonna test it again, maybe i didnt placed it on the right position in my page.
right now i placed it right before the ldap_bind, hope that will solve my problem.

Is the user an admin? Did you try with an admin to see if it works?

@Olivier the user is domain admin

What Cyclonecode said should be done anyway, even if it doesn't fix the problem... Is the base DN actually correct? DC=Top,DC=OrganizationTree does not look realistic at all (it implies your AD domain was top.organizationtree)... Are you able to do a ldap_read($conn, "", "(objectClass=*)", ["*"]) and if so, what entry does it return?

@user1686 Hello, the base DN is correct, i was masking it, it could be: example.com which means DC=example,DC=com i was just trying to make sure people will understand that i'm talking about the top of the tree in the LDAP / AD.
i'm still testing what Cyclonecode offered to add so far so good, but it's been like that before.
i will make sure to update the thread after the holiday because right now i'm blocked from accessing to my organization :)

Well, i dont really have an answer for my issue, it's either network issue that we had got fixed during the holiday or the suggestion by @Cyclonecode to add
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); 
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

into my code.
so far so good and data is being pulled none stop and smooth.
thanks for everyone who took the time reading and assisting with my issue.
